# Why doesn't my external hard drive appear in /dev?

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I want to mount my external HDD, but my Raspberry Pi can't recognize anything.

I loaded `usb-storage` with `modprobe`, but if I insert the HDD into the USB port, nothing changes. I can't see any changes neither in the `lsusb -l`, nor in `dmesg`, nor in `/var/log/everything.log`. If I insert my mouse or keyboard, or USB hub, I can see that the system recognizes it, but if I insert the HDD I can't see anything. Like nothing happened.

What should I do to mount my external HDD?

*I've tried it with two different HDDs; neither worked.*

Comment: What does `fdisk -l` say?

Comment: It only prints the sdcard, and its partitions.

Comment: Hmm... USB 2.0 right? What happens when you try to mount the partition? What is the model of the external HDD?

Comment: Is it self powered?

Comment: This is screaming power problems.

Comment: This is usb powered hard disk (not external adapter), I cant mount because I cant see in the /dev, cant even see in the log if inserted or not (nothing changes in log, but when i plug in mouse or usb hub)

Comment: The raspberry pi can't provide enough power for the HDD then. Sorry, but it will never work without using a powered USB hub.

Comment: Can u post this as an answer, so I can accept it. My luck that my monitor has powered usb hub :D

Comment: The USB-circuitry should report this to the kernel, and the kernel should say so in its logs.  Does anything show up in `dmesg`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From comments:

> This is usb powered hard disk (not external adapter), I cant mount because I cant see in the /dev, cant even see in the log if inserted or not (nothing changes in log, but when i plug in mouse or usb hub)

Unfortunately, the Raspberry Pi can often not supply enough power through the USB ports to support USB powered devices. My own external HDD does not work because of this, and I would assume you are encountering the same issue.

You can resolve this in one of 2 ways:

- by using some sort of **powered** USB hub, which takes it's power from an external source, such as an AC adaptor.
- by using a self-powered external hard drive, which again takes it's power from an external source, such as an AC adaptor.

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the [Raspberry Pi Schematics](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1090), on page 3, there is a 140mA fuse in series between the 5V supply and the Vcc of each of the USB ports. 140mA is not enough to run a USB HDD.